# How to toggle Log In and Sign Up on specific size(media queries)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What i'm trying to achieve is to toggle right side of my header(from Log in and Sign Up buttons) into hamburger menu icon on the specific size of browser(when resize i want to right side disappears and go to the hamburger menu)...

here's code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
         <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">

             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/test1.png" class="img-responsive" ></a>
          </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li class="login1"><a href="#">Log In |</a></li>
            <li class="login2"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li class="cart"><img src="images/cart.png"></li>
            <li class="text1"><p>(2)</p></li>
            <li class="text2"><p>total: $</p></li>
            <li class="checkout"><button type="button" class="btn">BUTTON</button></li>

          </ul>

         </div>
        </div>
       </div>






    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and CSS:

```
.navbar-header {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-nav a {
  color: rgb(60, 113, 132) !important;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 12px;
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}

.login1 {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.login1 a {
  color: rgb(149, 149, 149) !important;
}

.login2 {
  margin-left: -26px;
}

.login2 a {
  color: rgb(149, 149, 149) !important;
}

.subtotal {
  display: inline;
}

.cart {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.text1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  color: rgb(149, 149, 149) !important;
}

.text2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: rgb(149, 149, 149) !important;
}

.checkout button {
  background-color: rgb(108, 181, 173);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
}





@media (max-width: 1335px) {
  .navbar-nav li,
  .navbar-brand img {
    position: relative;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .login1 a,
  .login2 a,
  .cart img, {
    position: relative;
    right: 15px;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 1249px) {
  .navbar-nav li,
   {
    position: relative;
    right: 35px;
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .navbar-brand img {
    width: 147px;
    height: 56px;
  }

  .login1 a,
  .login2 a,
  .cart img,
  .checkout button,
  .text1 p,
  .text2 p {
    position: relative;
    right: 45px;
  }
}



@media (max-width: 1218px) {

}



@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .navbar-nav li {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

as you can see,in media query(max-width: 1218px) i want to right side disappears and go to hamburger menu..i hope i was clear

Comment: Why are you tagging a Bootstrap 3 question with `bootstrap-4`?

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try to add this media query for 1218 max-height

```
    @media (max-width: 1218px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes that's it,partially...i want to menu stays where it is(home,link,link...), but right part of the menu(log in and sign up button and else)  to go to hamburger menu...And at the end, when you resize browser to mobile screen,whole navbar should go to hamburger,just logo to stay visible